# Why does RealityKit memory does not clear after deinit called?

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit

I cannot manage to release my RealityKit `ARView()` from memory. I am aware that there were [similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53919730/7826293) with ARKit + SceneKit with workarounds which doesn't solve my problem, unfortunately.

The solutions above kind of work by removing everything "suspicious" manually. That is exactly what I did in an even wider scope:

```
func closeCurrentView(completion: (() -> Void)? = nil, isScanAnotherFloor: Bool = false) {
    if backgroundRenderingID != UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid {
        let app = UIApplication.shared
        app.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundRenderingID)
        self.backgroundRenderingID = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid
    }
    self.arView?.session.pause()
    self.arView?.session.delegate = nil
    self.arView?.scene.anchors.removeAll()
    self.arView?.removeFromSuperview()
    self.arView?.window?.resignKey()
    self.arView = nil
}
```

Memory will rise to 90MB to 250MB and once `deinit` is called it will reduce to 175MB, not clearing all the memory.

Also at the time of initializing, I set proper options too.

```
arView?.renderOptions = [
    .disableMotionBlur,
    .disableDepthOfField,
    .disablePersonOcclusion,
    .disableGroundingShadows,
    .disableFaceOcclusions,
    .disableHDR
]
```

But still no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### About memory leakage

Alas, RealityKit 2.0 / 1.0 developers can't deallocate `ARView` from heap memory because there is a poor-quality implementation on Apple's part. Even if you declare `arView` property as `weak` in SwiftUI, this instance will be ***immediately*** deallocated, so you can't use it. In UIKit, however, declaring `arView` as `weak` has no effect.

As you remember, ARC was firstly introduced in Objective-C and later implemented in Swift. It's quite possible that the `weak` and `unowned` functionality is not implemented for ARView for some reason, perhaps because RealityKit is tailored for Swift only – `@objc` attribute explicitly states this. It looks like ARView weak reference isn't tracked by ARC (or there's no an associated [Side Table](https://maximeremenko.com/swift-arc-weak-references)).

```
@available(macOS 10.15, iOS 13.0, *)
@objc open class ARView : ARViewBase { ... }
```

If you need more info, please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909045/how-to-deallocate-realitykit-arview/59910004#59910004) for details.

*(Tested in Xcode 14.3)*

Comment: thanks for a quick answer does anyone find any workaround for this issue?

Comment: I haven't seen any workaround for this problem yet...

Comment: I don't think there is supposed to be a workaround. This is because the memory from an old ARView has similar properties as a new ARView you might instantiate in the future. I guess it's just to make the ARView load faster when doing repeated AR tasks with different or reusing ARViews. I have noticed that if I repeatedly instantiate one ARView after ending the previous one, the memory usage does not increase and stays relatively the same.