# Memory Leak in a ARKit view using RealityKit and Vision

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, realitykit, vision

I made a little setup here to show how this is used. Whenever I dismiss the view, memory is retained. After going into the HandInteractionARViewContainer124 4 or 5 times, the app will crash.

Here is navigation. I heard that NavigationView has some memory problems so I'm using the latest NavigationStack view.

```
struct Nav : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: {
                    HandInteractionARViewContainer124().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                }, label: {
                    Text("AR View")
                        .padding(50)

                } )


                NavigationLink(destination: {
                    HandInteractionARViewContainer124().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                }, label: {
                    Text("AR View 2")
                        .padding(50)

                } )
               
                
            }
        }
       
    }
}
```

Here is the is where things get a little interesting:

I'm trying to load an RC file and use vision to post a notification trigger when touching the box entity with my hands.

```
struct HandInteractionARViewContainer124: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

 func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<HandInteractionARViewContainer124>) -> HandInteractionARViewController124 {
     let viewController = HandInteractionARViewController124()
     return viewController
 }

 func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: HandInteractionARViewController124, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<HandInteractionARViewContainer124>) {

 }

 func makeCoordinator() -> HandInteractionARViewContainer124.Coordinator {
     return Coordinator()
 }

 class Coordinator {

 }
}

class HandInteractionARViewController124: UIViewController, ARSessionDelegate {


 private var arView:ARView!
    let sceneUno = try! K128.loadScene()

 lazy var request:VNRequest = {
     var handPoseRequest = VNDetectHumanHandPoseRequest(completionHandler: handDetectionCompletionHandler)
     handPoseRequest.maximumHandCount = 1
     return handPoseRequest
 }()
 var viewWidth:Int = 0
 var viewHeight:Int = 0
 var box:ModelEntity!

 var boxButton:ModelEntity!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     arView = ARView(frame: view.bounds)
     arView.session.delegate = self
     view.addSubview(arView)
     let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
     config.environmentTexturing = .automatic
     config.frameSemantics = [.personSegmentation]
     config.planeDetection = [.horizontal]
     arView.session.run(config, options: [])
     viewWidth = Int(arView.bounds.width)
     viewHeight = Int(arView.bounds.height)
     setupObject()
 }


 private func setupObject(){
     let anchor = AnchorEntity(plane: .horizontal)

     let plane = ModelEntity(mesh: .generatePlane(width: 2, depth: 2), materials: [OcclusionMaterial()])

     anchor.addChild(plane)

     plane.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)

     plane.physicsBody = PhysicsBodyComponent(massProperties: .default, material: .default, mode: .static)

     box = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: 0.05), materials: [SimpleMaterial(color: .white, isMetallic: true)])
     box.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
     box.physicsBody = PhysicsBodyComponent(massProperties: .default, material: .default, mode: .dynamic)
     box.position = [0,0.025,0]



     anchor.addChild(sceneUno)
     anchor.addChild(box)

     arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
 }

 var recentIndexFingerPoint:CGPoint = .zero

 func handDetectionCompletionHandler(request: VNRequest?, error: Error?) {



     guard let observation = request?.results?.first as? VNHumanHandPoseObservation else { return }

     guard let indexFingerTip = try? observation.recognizedPoints(.all)[.indexTip],
           indexFingerTip.confidence > 0.3 else {return}

     let normalizedIndexPoint = VNImagePointForNormalizedPoint(CGPoint(x: indexFingerTip.location.y, y: indexFingerTip.location.x), viewWidth,  viewHeight)

     if let entity = arView.entity(at: normalizedIndexPoint) as? ModelEntity, entity == box {
        entity.addForce([0,40,0], relativeTo: nil)
         sceneUno.notifications.flipFlop.post()
     }
     recentIndexFingerPoint = normalizedIndexPoint
 }

 func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
     let pixelBuffer = frame.capturedImage
     DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] in
         let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer, orientation: .up, options: [:])
         do {
             try handler.perform([(self?.request)!])

         } catch let error {
             print(error)
         }
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: Read this post for details – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71678361/why-does-realitykit-memory-does-not-clear-after-deinit-called/71844537#71844537